# insert excel table into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to create a set of web pages. Each has a table in it(say). Also the user of this webpage needs to do operations like search,etc. in the table. But he would also like the table to be in an excel sheet and not defined inside the webpage so that he can add rows or columns or edit existing data anytime he likes.

I converted the excel file into a HTML page using Save As->Web Page->Publish. Now I tried to include the source code of that HTML file into my web page HTML so that I can directly access the table using getElementByTagName("table").

To do this I tried several ways I found searching online.

First way

```
<div w3-include-html="animals.html"></div>
```

Second way

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $('#header').load("animals.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

Third way

```
<!--#include file="animals.html" -->
```

Fourth way

```
<iframe> tag
```

None of these seem to work. Also please remember I can't change the source code of animals.html as I got it from the excel and not by typing it. I am new to javascript and HTML so if there is some obvious way I am missing please help me out. If not the HTML file tell me some other way I can import the table from the Excel into my HTML code so I can do some operations on it.

I do not know JQuery,PHP,ASP,SQL,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just fire an AJAX request on your HTML page and put response of AJAX inside a container like `<div>`.

```
$.get('animals.html', function(response ){
    // put response at some div,
    $('div').html(response);
});
```

also dont forget to add this in `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should open your `animals.html` file directly in the browser with same path as you give in 1st parameter in `$.get` function and check if it opens.

Comment: I inserted the code using <object> tag. But var y = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); does not get the table in y[0]. Is it because of the <html> tag in the inserted html file?

Comment: Can you see your `HTML table` in console?

Comment: Using console.table() right? Its not showing. I used                                  <object data="file.html" type="text/html"></object>                                         Here is file.html   (Just a table):          <html><body><table><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr><tr><td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td></tr></table></body></html>

Comment: Ok, no you cant access `<table>` tag by `<object>`.